# Determinant of $A$, $a_{ij}=a_i+a_j$, if $i\neq j$, otherwise $a_{ij}=0$. How to do it?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Determinant of $A$, $a_{ij}=a_i+a_j$, if $i\neq j$, otherwise $a_{ij}=0$. How to do it? Here $a_i\neq 0$ for any $i$.

It seems quite difficult. Since any usual method does not apply. Add one line $1,a_1,\cdots,a_n$, and substracting. then it is still not clear.

Comment: your matrix has all zeros on the main diagonal and is symmetric. would help to know what $a_i,a_j$ are as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)^T,\, D=\operatorname{diag}(a) ,\,B=\pmatrix{a&e}$ and $C=\pmatrix{e&a}$. By Sylvester determinant theorem $\det(I+XY)=\det(I+YX)$, we obtain
\begin{aligned}
\det(A)
&=\det(-2D+BC^T)\\
&=\det(-2D)\det\left(I_n-\frac12D^{-1}BC^T\right)\\
&=\det(-2D)\det\left(I_2-\frac12C^TD^{-1}B\right)\\
&=\det(-2D)\det\pmatrix{1-\frac12e^TD^{-1}a&-\frac12e^TD^{-1}e\\ -\frac12a^TD^{-1}a&1-\frac12a^TD^{-1}e}\\
&=\det(-2D)\left[\left(1-\frac{n}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac12\sum_i\frac{1}{a_i}\right)\left(\frac12\sum_ia_i\right)\right]\\
&=(-2)^{n-2}\left(\prod_ia_i\right)\left[(n-2)^2-\left(\sum_i\frac{1}{a_i}\right)\left(\sum_ia_i\right)\right].\\
\end{aligned}